# Implement Windows Identity Foundation on PHP

Tags: php, wif

Need some advice whether Windows Identity Foundation can work with PHP platform or not?
I know that WIF is targeted for .NET framework, and 1 of its features is about Single-Sign On kind of feature.
What do I need to do in order to include the WIF's features to PHP client domain sites?

Answer (score 4):

Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) provides single sign-on capabilities through the [SAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language) protocol, which is an open standard.  So to implement WIF functionality in PHP, you just need to use one of the SAML PHP libraries.

There are several out there, but [SimpleSAML](http://simplesamlphp.org/) is probably the most robust, and I was able to make it work for a PHP application that accepted claims from an AD FS STS.  We also used the same library within Drupal (with slight modifications) to enable single sign-on.

Hope this helps.